# Adding npm packaged dependencies to svn

Tags: svn, npm

I'm packaging up a node project that has some dependencies installed with npm. The code will be deployed on an npm-less server, so I used npm bundle to make a node_modules directory with all the dependencies.

The node_modules just is a bunch of symlinks that look like `depname`, which point to symlinks that look like `depname@X.X.X`, which point to directories in `./.npm/`, where the actual dependencies are.

The problem is that when I try to `svn add` any of these symlinks with an `@` in their name, svn just complains that the folder it's linking to is already under version control.

for instance:

```
$ svn add jsdom\@0.2.3
```

results in:

```
svn: warning: 'jsdom' is already under version control
```

when I svn stat though, I still see `jsdom@0.2.3` as unversioned.

I'm super confused - I'm sure it's something simple, but I'm definitely missing something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Appears that the issue was with svn confusing the @ with a revision. Adding another @ at the end of the file fixed it:

```
svn add jsdom\@0.2.3\@
```

works like it should.